# Global Hook in WriteProcessMemory function

Tags: delphi

I wonder how can I make a detour of a function, as WriteProcessMemory for example?

As the WriteProcessMemory Monitor:

[Image WriteProcessMemoryMonitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvzK7.png)

http://www.novirusthanks.org

Comment: Hooking API calls involves a detour. Unrelated to WH_KEYBOARD. More clarity in the question is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not speak fluent English. I need to do a global hook on WriteProcessMemory function, I wonder if it is possible with the SetWindowsHookEx?

Comment: No it is not. You need a detour.

Comment: Could you tell me a function that does this?

Comment: Not if you ask the question in comments. Please read the [help] and edit the question to ask what you really want answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to create a D-Tour

You need a record like this :

```
unit PatchU;

interface

type
  TPatchMethod = record
  private type
    pPatchEvent = ^TPatchEvent;

    // "Asm" opcode hack to patch an existing routine
    TPatchEvent = packed record
      Jump: Byte;
      Offset: Integer;
    end;

  var
    PatchedMethod, OriginalMethod: TPatchEvent;
    PatchPositionMethod: pPatchEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(const aSource, aDestination: Pointer);
    procedure Restore;
    procedure Hook;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Windows, Sysutils;

{ TPatchMethod }

constructor TPatchMethod.Create(const aSource, aDestination: Pointer);
var
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  PatchPositionMethod := pPatchEvent(aSource);
  OriginalMethod := PatchPositionMethod^;
  PatchedMethod.Jump := $E9;
  PatchedMethod.Offset := PByte(aDestination) - PByte(PatchPositionMethod) - SizeOf(TPatchEvent);

  if not VirtualProtect(PatchPositionMethod, SizeOf(TPatchEvent), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  Hook;
end;


procedure TPatchMethod.Hook;
begin
  PatchPositionMethod^ := PatchedMethod;
end;

procedure TPatchMethod.Restore;
begin
  PatchPositionMethod^ := OriginalMethod;
end;

end.
```

And then use it:

```
var
  TcxLabel_Patch: TPatchMethod;
```

...

```
type
  THooked_cxLabel = class(TcxLabel)
    constructor HookedCreate(AOwner: TComponent);
  end;
```

...

```
  THooked_cxImage = class(TcxImage)
    constructor HookedCreate(AOwner: TComponent);
  end;

constructor THooked_cxLabel.HookedCreate(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  TcxLabel_Patch.Restore;
  try
    Create(AOwner);
    Transparent := True;
  finally
    TcxLabel_Patch.Hook;
  end;
end;
```

...

```
initialization
  TcxLabel_Patch := TPatchMethod.Create(@TcxLabel.Create, @THooked_cxLabel.HookedCreate);
finalization
end.
```

In this example I hook the constructor of a tcxalbel. But you can hook everything.

Comment: Asker wants this hook to apply in all processes I think

Comment: As far as I know you can only make this D-tour indise your own process.

Comment: It's possible to detour API calls in other processes

Comment: @JensBorrisholt thank you for responding, but it is a Global Hook What do I want to. I apologize for the trouble I caused the posts.

Comment: @SCOFIELD You don't seem willing to learn how to use this site. The question is not clear. Please can you edit it to make it clear what you are looking for.

Comment: To detour an API globally, you need to apply the detour in every running process that uses the API. Which mean you have to inject code into every running process. Put your detouring code into a DLL, and then call `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a global hook where the hook callback is in the DLL. The DLL will then be injected into every process. Whenever the DLL is loaded into a new process, it can detour that process's API functions as needed. Just note that you will need 32bit and 64bit versions of the DLL for 64bit systems.

Comment: See [Using SetWindowsHookEx for DLL Injection on Windows](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-setwindowshookex-for-dll-injection-on-windows/) and [DLL Injection Part 1: SetWindowsHookEx](https://warroom.securestate.com/index.php/dll-injection-part-1-setwindowshookex/) for more details.